# Individual attachments in mail merge from thunderbird

Tags: libreoffice, email, thunderbird, mail, csv

I am trying to send multiple emails with unique fields from thunderbird with mail merge addon in ubuntu. How to add individual attachments using this method?
I have tried adding a separate field **Attachment** in the **.ods** file and by adding file names in the format **/home/user/Doc/1.pdf**. But the files are not getting uploaded to the mail by using {{Attachment}} in the composed mail, only the text is /home/user/Doc/1.pdf shown. Also, the **To** section is not supporting {{Email}}, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**To section is not supporting `{{Email}}`**

Use `{{Email}}<>` instead of `{{Email}}`.
It works.

Answer (score 0):

I came across because of the first problem, for which I search an answer too. To your 2nd question: Just hit RETURN, so that TB changes your {{Email}} to a useable one...